# ubuntu 12.04 server comes with Odd Kernel Development version.How can it be upgraded??

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-12.04

I have downloaded latest ubuntu server edition but after installing its showing kernel of 3.2.0-23 Generic kernel,which is a development version.
So how can i change to stable release with out compiling??

Comment: I'm no kernel pro but why do you think the 3.2.0-23 kernel is a development kernel?

Comment: doesnt odd kernel number indicates development version?

Comment: Yes, but this is even. 3.3.x is development.

Comment: so which field should i lokk into?? second??huh?

Comment: thanx for the minus :-)

Comment: And jsut to add something: Canonical would rather not add a dev kernel to a long term version of ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put this stuff in a real answer: You have a production version. Linux version numbering has changed a lot  and the odd/even method haven't been used since 2.6.0 has been published years ago, as there are no development kernel versions anymore like in 2.3.x or 2.5.x

In 3.*x* the *x* has the same meaning as it had in 2.6.*x*, and it's just an increasing number, with 2 following 1.

See https://lwn.net/Articles/452531/